# Why div inside div is color is not changing through JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

```js
    var ar = ['.two_in','.three_in','.four_in'], pb =  "> *";
    ar.forEach(function(x){       
    var sel = document.querySelectorAll( x + pb);
    
        var colors = {};       
        colors[ar[0]] = 'blue';
        colors[ar[1]] = 'green';
        colors[ar[2]] = 'red';
        
    for(var i = 0;i<sel.length;i++){
    sel[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[sel[i].className];
    }  
  })
```

```html
<div class="two_in">
  <div class="demo">blue</div>
  <div class="demo">blue</div>
  <div class="demo">blue</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="three_in">
  <div class="demo">green</div>
  <div class="demo">green</div>
  <div class="demo">green</div>
</div>
<br>

<div class="four_in">
  <div class="demo">red</div>
  <div class="demo">red</div>
  <div class="demo">red</div>
</div>
```

I want to change all div color inside `two_in` to blue, `three_in` to green, and `four_in` to red respectively, what's the missing code? Can anyone explain it?

**Example:**

The all div inside `two_in` (three div whose div class is `demo`) should be blue color and as for the `three_in` and `four_in`.

Comment: You sure you can't add jQuery?

Comment: Your query selector is for what's inside each main class ....so `sel[i].className` will always be `demo` in example shown

Comment: yeah @PraveenKumar , why that doesnt working

Comment: `sel[i].className` is `'demo'` and `colors` does not contain `demo` property. so, `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the mistake:

```
colors[ar[0]] = 'blue';
colors[ar[1]] = 'green';
colors[ar[2]] = 'red';
```

It is assigning a non primitive index there. What you need to is:

```js
var ar = ['.two_in', '.three_in', '.four_in'],
    pb = " > *";
ar.forEach(function(x) {
  var sel = document.querySelectorAll(x + pb);
  var colors = {};
  colors[0] = 'blue';
  colors[1] = 'green';
  colors[2] = 'red';

  for (var i = 0; i < sel.length; i++) {
    sel[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="two_in">
  <div class="demo">blue</div>
  <div class="demo">blue</div>
  <div class="demo">blue</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="three_in">
  <div class="demo">green</div>
  <div class="demo">green</div>
  <div class="demo">green</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="four_in">
  <div class="demo">red</div>
  <div class="demo">red</div>
  <div class="demo">red</div>
</div>
```

Is the above what you want? Or, if you need the colour based on the text, then...

```js
var ar = ['.two_in', '.three_in', '.four_in'],
    pb = " > *";
ar.forEach(function(x) {
  var sel = document.querySelectorAll(x + pb);
  var colors = {};
  colors['blue'] = 'blue';
  colors['green'] = 'green';
  colors['red'] = 'red';

  for (var i = 0; i < sel.length; i++) {
    sel[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[sel[i].innerHTML.trim()];
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="two_in">
  <div class="demo">blue</div>
  <div class="demo">blue</div>
  <div class="demo">blue</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="three_in">
  <div class="demo">green</div>
  <div class="demo">green</div>
  <div class="demo">green</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="four_in">
  <div class="demo">red</div>
  <div class="demo">red</div>
  <div class="demo">red</div>
</div>
```

Comment: but it doesnt auto taking the color with classname

Comment: @Anjali Sorry, didn't understand. What?

Comment: chat discussion